# Controlling the power from a 9V battery with a potentiometer

Tags: lcd, potentiometer

I'm working on a project where I'm powering an LCD screen backlight via a 9V battery. As it is currently, I'm powering the LCD via a 9V battery.

This works great, but I'd like to have the ability to easily change the brightness via adjusting the voltage with a potentiometer. I have a 10k Ohm one currently, but that only works when it's fully on. Anything less, and the screen is off.

Would a higher Ohm potentiometer solve this issue, or is there a better solution?

Comment: All LCD screens that I have used have high-Z input pins to control brightness. Are you talking about this kind of design or are you placing the potentiometer inline with the supply to the screen?

Comment: @sherrellbc I was going to place the potentiometer inline with the supply as that's the only thing I can really do (or want to do.) It's just a small LCD backlight from a portable DVD player I took apart and I decided to hack it into a light soft-box.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, is 9V the supply voltage of the backlight? LEDs usually have voltages of about 3V, and a higher voltage usually destroys them immediately. Maybe, there are multiple LED in series and a resistor in your display.

Your problem is the characteristic U-I curve of LEDs. A little lower voltage, and the current drops significantly, and the LED becomes much dimmer.

If your potentiometer is too large, a small angle will already cause a high resistance, which does not allow enough current to flow through the LEDs. Hence, a *smaller* potentiometer may help. Also, have a look at logarithmic potentiometers. As said, the correlation of angle and resistance is logarithmic, so the resistance will change only a little over a wide range of the angle. This allows a very fine adjustment of the current.

However, I wonder that the LED is fully off as soon as you touch the potentiometer... Also, you have to take into account the power dissipation of your backlight. Potentiometers usually can not dissipate much power, and depending on your backlight, you may overload it.

Another solution would be a PWM, for example using a NE555. Here is an example from

http://www.reuk.co.uk/LED-Dimmer-Circuit.htm :

[image]

The benefit is that there is a linear potentiometer, and the output power also depends linearly on the potentiometer setting. Also, the behavior is independent from the load connected.

Comment: I'm guessing the display is several LEDs and a resistor, as I connected up the display directly a while before having this project idea and it didn't blow out. I'll look into using that PWM solution, it might work just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

No, a potentiometer is not really suitable for this job.

You could use a much lower resistance potentiometer as a variable resistor, but the currents involved at higher brightnesses would probably burn out the carbon track.

Instead you should control the back light through a transistor and drive that transistor with a PWM signal.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to use a transistor as an emitter follower:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK33hQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The benefit is the simplicity of the circuit, you only need to add a NPN transistor to your potentiometer.

The drawback compared to the PWM solution is that the output can only go up to about 8.3v (so you can't achieve the full brightness), and the power consumption, since the excess voltage (input-output difference) multiplied by the output current is consumed on the transistor as heat.